# Expansion of a Majorana field operator in creation and annihilation operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spinors, majorana-fermions

A Dirac spinor $\Psi=\left(\begin{array}{c}\chi_\alpha\\\psi^\dot{\alpha}\end{array} \right)$ can be expanded in the following way:$\Psi=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2E_p}} \sum_s\left( u_s(p)a_{s p} \exp(-ipx) + v_s(p) b^{\dagger}_{s p} \exp(ipx) \right)$.

In particular we have $v(p) = u(p)^c$ where $x^c$ means the charge conjugated expression of $x$.

I was always wondering how a Majorana spinor would be expanded in a similar way. Actually, I found that this expansion is a exercise in the book of Peskin & Schroeder, exercise 3.4(e). Furthermore I even found solutions on the internet "published" by Zhong-Zhi Xianyou. He states that a 2-dim. Majorana spinor could be expanded in creation and annihilation operators in the following way ($\xi_s$ must be the spin-components of some 2-dim. spinor)

$\chi(x) =\int  \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\sqrt{\frac{p\cdot \sigma}{2E_p}} \sum_s\left[\xi_s a_{s p}\exp(-ipx) + (-i\sigma^2)\xi^{*}_s a^{\dagger}_{s p}\exp(ipx)\right]$

However, I cannot understand it. Actually, I have the impression that $\xi_s$ and  $(-i\sigma^2)\xi^{*}_s$ don't transform in the same way under Lorentz-transformations. $\xi\equiv \xi_\alpha$ seems to transform like normal Weyl-spinor, 
whereas $(-i\sigma^2)\xi^{*}_s \equiv \xi^\dot{\alpha}$ seems to transform like a dotted Weyl-spinor but are added up both in the same expression which would mix up the transformation properties.

According to the appendix E in A.Zee's book a charge-conjugated 4-Dirac spinor has the following form:
$\Psi^c=\left(\begin{array}{c}\psi_\alpha\\\chi^\dot{\alpha}\end{array} \right)$
If I apply this representation on $u(p)$, then with $v(p)=u(p)^c$ I get the correct behaviour of $v(p)$ under Lorentz-transformations. Both upper components of $u(p)$ and $v(p)$ are undotted Weyl-spinors whereas the both lower components are both dotted Weyl-spinors. So for the expansion of the Dirac-spinor there is no contradiction (of course not!). 
From this I was tempted to write down my own expression for $\chi(x)$, but finally I realized that $u$ and $v$ are still solutions of the Dirac-equation, therefore the relation for Majorana-spinors $v(p)$=$u^c(p)$=$u(p)$ is a wrong short-cut. So at this point I don't know to proceed further. 
Can somebody help me out? Thank you.

Comment: A Majorana spinor has the form $\Psi = \begin{pmatrix} \chi_\alpha \\ {\bar \chi}^{\dot \alpha} \end{pmatrix}$ or in other words $\psi_\alpha = \chi_\alpha$. So just take the mode expansion you have for the Dirac spinor and impose the constraint above on $u_s$ and $v_s$ and you will have the mode expansion of the Majorana spinor.

Comment: @Prahar: Thank you, I would appreciate if you could say a bit more on how to obtain the correct mode expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to get to the expansion of $\chi(x)$ is to continue what you started as @Prahar also suggested. Take a 4-component Majorana field $\psi(x)$ with the Majorana condition [$a_{s}(p)=b_{s}(p)$] and apply the left-chiral projector $P_L$ or take the left-chiral component $\chi_\alpha$. Write $u_s(p)$ and $v_s(p)$ according do Peskin, eqs.(3.50) and (3.62), and extract the left-chiral component, i.e., the first two components. This leads to the expansion in your question. Beware to choose $\xi^s$ and $\eta^s$ so that the convention $u_s^c(p)=v_s(p)$ is satisfied; it is not automatic.

Now, about your impression that $i\sigma_2\xi_s^*$ is transforming in the wrong way under Lorentz, you are forgetting the factor $\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma}$ in front. This factor performs the boost in the $p$ direction and sets the Lorentz transformation behaviour: both spinors are left chiral. 
The spinors $\xi_s$ and $i\sigma_2\xi_s^*$ defines the spin direction in the rest frame and $i\sigma_2(~)^*$ just flips the spin as time reversal in quantum mechanics. For simplicity, you can use the $z$-direction and spin up and down for $\xi_s$.

Comment: This is a great answer. Just in order to confirm my understanding, so the Lorentz boost acts on $\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma}$ whereas an associated rotation would act on $\xi_s$ and $i\sigma_2 \xi_s^{\ast}$. Is that right? It is also interesting to observe that the created Majorana particle has apparently opposite spin to the annihilated particle.

Comment: The correct statement would be "Lorentz boost effectively acts _as_ $\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma}$". The whole positive frequency spinor is $\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma}\xi_s$ which is constructed following the idea: take a spinor at rest with a specific spin direction and boost it in the $p$ direction. It is this spinor that transforms in a specific manner under Lorentz.

Answer (score 1):

***"...seems to transform like a dotted Weyl-spinor but are added up both in the same expression which would mix up the transformation properties..."***

Suppose the $\left( 1/2, 0\right)$ Lorentz transformation 
$$
\psi_{a} \to \left(\text{exp}\left[ \frac{\sigma_{\mu\nu}\omega^{\mu\nu}}{2}\right]\psi\right)_{a}, \quad\text{with}\quad \sigma_{\mu\nu} = -\frac{1}{4}(\sigma_{\mu}\tilde{\sigma}_{\nu} - \sigma_{\nu}\tilde{\sigma}_{\mu}),
$$
where
$$
\sigma_\mu = (1, \sigma), \quad \tilde{\sigma}_\mu =(1,-\sigma)
$$ 
Then the spinor $(\sigma_{2}\psi^{*})_{a}$ is transformed as
$$
(\sigma_{2}\psi^{*})_{a} \to \left(\sigma_{2}\text{exp}\left[\frac{\sigma^{*}_{\mu\nu}\omega^{\mu\nu}}{2}\right]\psi^{*}\right)_{a} = \left(\text{exp}\left[\sigma_{2}\sigma_{\mu\nu}^{*}\sigma_{2}\frac{\omega^{\mu\nu}}{2}\right] \sigma_{2}\psi^{*}\right)_{a}
$$
But with the rule $\sigma_{\mu}^{*} = -\sigma_{2}\sigma_{\mu}\sigma_{2}$, $\tilde{\sigma}_{\mu}^{*} = -\sigma_{2}\tilde{\sigma}_{\mu}\sigma_{2}$ the transformation is nothing but
$$
(\sigma_{2}\psi^{*})_{a} \to \left(\text{exp}\left[ \frac{1}{2}\sigma_{\mu\nu}\omega^{\mu\nu}\right]\sigma_{2}\psi^{*}\right)_{a},
$$
which is the same as for ordinary $\psi_{a}$.

This is quite obvious since the charge conjugation, through which we define the Majorana spinor, is just the analog of complex conjugation on the space of spinors.

***...Can somebody help me out?..***

Just start from the general expansion of the creation-destruction field for the Dirac field:
$$
\hat{\Psi}_{A}(x) = \sum_{\sigma}\int \frac{d^{3}\mathbf p}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{3}2E_{\mathbf p}}}\left(c_{1}u_{A}^{\sigma}(\mathbf p)\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{\sigma}(\mathbf p)e^{ipx} + c_{2}v_{A}^{\sigma}(\mathbf p)\hat{a}_{\sigma}(\mathbf p)e^{-ipx}\right) 
$$
The Majorana condition
$$
\hat{\Psi}(x) = C\hat{\bar{\Psi}}^{T}(x), \quad C = i\gamma_{0}\gamma_{2}
$$ 
which separates the subspace of the Lorentz group representations $T(\Lambda)$ for which $T(\Lambda)$ and $T^{*}(\Lambda)$ are equivalent, relates $u_{\sigma}(\mathbf p)$ to $v_{\sigma}(\mathbf p)$. After some algebra, we obtain
$$
v_{\sigma}(\mathbf p) = \bar{u}^{T}_{\sigma}(\mathbf p) = -(-1)^{1/2+\sigma}C\gamma_{5}u_{-\sigma}(\mathbf p)
$$